# Traefik not seeing Docker Swarm services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm currently learning how to use Traefik and Docker Swarm, and to that end I've been trying to set up a simple whoami service that Traefik can route to. However, no matter what I try, I can't get Traefik to see any Docker Swarm services. Here is my compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
        traefik:
                image: "traefik:v2.0.0"
                command:
                        - --entrypoints.web.address=:80 # Enables listening to HTTP requests
                        #- --providers.docker=true # Enables Docker support
                        - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true # Enables Docker Swarm Mode support
                        - --providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 # ???
                        - --api.insecure # Activates the web ui in insecure mode
                ports:
                        - "80:80" # Binds port 80 (HTTP)
                        - "8080:8080" # Binds port 8080 (Web UI)
                volumes:
                        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro" # Enables listening to Docker state
                deploy:
                        labels:
                                - traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
                        placement:
                                constraints: [node.role==manager]

        whoami:
                image: "containous/whoami:v1.3.0"
                deploy:
                        labels:
                                - traefik.port=80
                                - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`testificate.com`)
                                - traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Your docker-compose.yml file had problems. such as:

```
#- --providers.docker=true
```

you should open it.

```
- --providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

you told traefik to use tcp://127.0.0.1:2375, but you set /var/run/docker.sock.

whoami and traefik labels don't have entrypoints, like below:

traefik:

```
- traefik.http.routers.traefik-http.entrypoints=web
```

whoami:

```
- traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web
```

and you should set network tag for traefik. like below:

```
TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_NETWORK=XXX
```